# Difference in results between case syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have been playing around with CASE syntax and noticed the following difference in behaviour which I don't full understand.

Given the below query

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT 

SELECT 
    'Col1' = CASE WHEN @Value1 IS NULL THEN 'Yay'
    ELSE 'Oh'
    END
    ,'Col2' = CASE @Value1 WHEN NULL THEN 'Yay'
    ELSE 'Oh'
    END
    ,'Val' = @Value1
```

The result set I am getting is this:

> Col1 | Col2 | Val
>
> Yay | Oh | NULL

I would have thought they would return the same result. Would anyone be happy to explain what's going here?

Comment: Because the `CASE @Value1 WHEN NULL THEN 'Yay'  ELSE 'Oh' END` is equivalent to `CASE WHEN @Value1 = NULL THEN 'Yay'  ELSE 'Oh' END`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same reason Col3 I've added below returns "Oh". In your Col2 you are testing if NULL equals @Value1. NULL is undefined, it doesn't equal anything. As Codd would say

> Rule 3: Systematic treatment of null values:
>
> The DBMS must allow each field to remain null (or empty). Specifically, it must support a representation of "missing information and inapplicable information" that is systematic, distinct from all regular values (for example, "distinct from zero or any other number", in the case of numeric values), and independent of data type. It is also implied that such representations must be manipulated by the DBMS in a systematic way.

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT 

SELECT 
    'Col1' = CASE WHEN @Value1 IS NULL THEN 'Yay'
    ELSE 'Oh'
    END
    ,'Col2' = CASE @Value1 WHEN NULL THEN 'Yay'
    ELSE 'Oh'
    END
    ,'Col3' = CASE WHEN NULL = NULL  THEN 'Yay'
    ELSE 'Oh'
    END
    ,'Val' = @Value1
```

Comment: right gotcha - I was mistakenly expecting an unknown value to be equal to another unknown value. Many Thanks!